# Make floating boxes fit empty space

Tags: html, css, position, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to make a layout where four boxes float and have different widths and heights. They are in a 2x2 grid.

What I got so far works but has one case where it doesn't do what I need, and is represented in the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ULjCK/2/

The layout is pretty basic in this demo:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell wide short">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell clear-left">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
</div>
```

I'd like box 3 to take the space available above it, and be placed right next to box 1.
If I make two boxes float left and two boxes float right I kinda solve this issue, but I get the same issue horizontally.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery Masonry. The problem has already been solved. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Floating does not work as you think it might.  It does not fill gaps above the bottom of the line above it.  You will have to position these absolutely or get something like masonry mentioned above.

Comment: Masonry has a fixed column size. So elements use available vertical space but not available horizontal space. It produces the same problem with a different orientation. (I haven't used masonry, just read the docs)

Comment: Would you object to using a sorting algorithm in javascript and have the js place the boxes?

Comment: It's my current option, just wanted to ask the CSS gurus around. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

How about just giving the third cell a negative margin-top? It works fine; see the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ULjCK/4/.

Code:

```
.clear-left {
    clear: left;
    margin-top: -25px; /* added */
}
```